# Given a super number a=12435 and a normal number b=45. check if the given number b is in the same sequence of a or not?

Tags: java

```
If I enter a=12435
and b=45 as they are in the sequence return true
a=12435
b=54 as they are not in sequence return false.
I think i can accept an input number as a string and split it into char array but I wanted to use only INT arrays.That is what the problem i am facing.Thanks in   advance.
```

How to perform whether the number b is in the same sequence of a after determining that a is a super number?

Comment: u want to compare each digit??  what should return if i set a=13425 and b=45?  u are comparing each digits of both numbers??

Comment: true as b is in the same sequence of a

Comment: a=15234 and b=54 then it would true right????

Comment: yes it needs to return true

Comment: What have you tried so far?  (Other than "I tried to get StackOverflow readers to write my code for me.")

Comment: break the number(b) and check the position of both   digits in a and compare.

Comment: get the last digit of each of a and b. if they are equal, get the next digit of a and b. if  they were not equal , get the next digit of a and compare. if no digit is remaining in b, return true else return false

Comment: Take a number. Select the digit in ones position. Check whether the number is present in the second number. If the number is present in second number, truncate the second number to the right including the matching digit. Now again, try the find the second digit of the first number in the second number. And so on. Iterate until the end of first number. If in each iteration match is found return true else return false

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean verify(String a, String b){
    if("".equals(b)){
        return true;
    }
    int locate = a.indexOf(String.valueOf(b.charAt(0)));
    if(locate == -1){
        return false;
    }else{
        return verify(a.substring(locate + 1), b.substring(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: firstly, check whether if the first character of string b is existed in a, if not existed, return false; if existed, and the index is i, then using the same logic to judge whether if the string b without the first character the sequence of a.

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to keep track of the sequence of matched characters. 
When a match is found, that character is removed to prevent potential errors when working with sequences containing duplicate characters.

```
public bool IsInSequence(string a, string b)
                    {
                        int lowestIndex = -1;

                        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
                        {
                            var index = b.IndexOf(a[i]);

                            if (index != -1)
                            {
                                if (index >= lowestIndex)
                                {
                                    lowestIndex = index;
                                    b = b.Remove(index,1);
                                    --i;
                                }
                                else
                                    return false;
                            }
                        }

                        return lowestIndex > -1;
                    }
```

Comment: what does b.indexOf(a[i]) return and i had a doubt whether a is a string or an array?

Comment: What language is this? It certainly isn't Java.

Comment: b.indexOf(a[i]) returns -1 if no letter of a is present in b, else it returns the index that letter is at. A string is just an array of chars.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert to `String`s as other answers suggest: just check to see if the last digit of the super number (`a`) matches the last digit of the normal number (`b`).

- If they're the same, divide both numbers by 10, so you'll compare the next digit along next time;
- If they're different, just divide `a` by 10, as that digit isn't the next one you're looking for.

Repeat this until either number hits zero; if `a` matched `b`, then `b` will now be zero.

```
while (a != 0 && b != 0) {
  if (a % 10 == b % 10) {
    b /= 10;
  }
  a /= 10;
}
return b == 0;
```

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        int a=sc.nextInt();
        int b=sc.nextInt();
        boolean s=verify(a,b);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    public static boolean verify(int a, int b){
        while (a != 0 && b != 0) {
            if (a % 10 == b % 10) {
                b /= 10;
            }
            a /= 10;
        }
        return a == 0 && b == 0;
    }
}It is returning false even b is insequence

Comment: if a matched b, then both numbers will now be zero and return statement returns true but even when a=12435 and b=45 is given it is printing false.

Comment: this is the best and optimal solution i would like to give an upvote but sry as i have no reputation.

Comment: @mahesh FYI it's easier if you post a link to ideone.com (or similar site) to show an example of code not working, as it's basically unreadable in a comment.